# GWT : CSS styles not reflecting in UI

Tags: javascript, html, css, gwt

I Created a CSS file in my project ,and i linked this file in the HTML host page like,

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="X.css">
```

But the styles are not reflecting in the UI.I don't know why this happens.The CSS file is in same directory of html host page.

Edit : I tried adding closing tag for link.It did not work.

Comment: you are missing close tag of link.

Comment: @PawanLakhara `link` elements have no closing tag

Comment: @chris97ong when i remove the closing tag of link its give warning "attributes and values are not valid inside closing tag".

Comment: @chris97ong : So what am i missing here.? Is the CSS style i have is correct?.

Comment: @Karthik207 just check your "href" path.

Comment: @PawanLakhara : CSS file is in the same of html host page.

Comment: Put css in particular page in style tag and check.

Comment: What do you mean by particular page in style tag?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use !important with the css classes as they might be conflicting with some predefined classes

```
.gwt-Tree table {
    table-layout: fixed !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
.gwt-Tree table td:first-child {
    width: 18px !important;
}
```

Comment: Is that mandatory to have closing tag? . I have seen some projects which don't have closing tag for <link>.

Comment: It depends, if you using html4 then you can avoid closing of link tag if you using xhtml then it is required. If you using html5 it works either ways

Comment: Sorry not allowed to create such things!.

Comment: I dont get any errors as well.Is the above CSS style correct?.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58055/discussion-between-v31-and-karthik207).

Answer (score 0):

Try href="/X.css" in this link. And check in your browser if the CSS file loads successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to empty your cache and hard reload. To do this in Google Chrome, open the Developer Tools (<kbd>F12</kbd> in Windows) and then right click on the reload button. From there select `Empty Cache and Hard Reload`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can add your css file into your .html as your app will be compiled

You can have a look at this, where it's defining the CSS to use into the module of your app : https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/GettingStartedStyle